# recursively print character using while and if

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm beginner and try to understand how recursion works.
what is the different of using while and if int the code?
why if i use  "if" it produce correct result?
but "while" doesn't? 
while(*k) ,when it reach "\0" then it print only once then it goes back to while loop again 
thank you so much for the help!!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 void back(char*k){
     if(*k) // works
     //while(*k) ->not work??
         back(++k);
     printf("%c",*k);
 }

 int main()
 {
     char k[]="hellomynameis";
     back(k);
     printf("Hello world!\n");
     return 0;
 }
```

is there possible way to do same thing in c++ but using iterator?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void backk(string a){
    string::iterator itr;
    for (itr=a.begin();itr!=a.end();itr++){
        if (*itr)
            backk(++itr);
        cout<<a; --> is this possible  ?

        //simple and fast solution 
        for (itr=a.end();itr!=a.begin();itr--){
            if(*itr)
                cout<<*itr;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string a("hello my name is");
    backk(a);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about `for (itr=a.rbegin();itr!=a.rend();++itr) std::cout << *itr;`?

Comment: Use recursion **instead** of using a loop. In simple cases like this recursion is just a different kind of loop and the if statement controls whether the looping continues or not. Using recursion and a while loop makes no sense (in a simple example like this).

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Be aware of the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). [Use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to run your program step by step, so you'll understand what is going on.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thankyou! im using codeblock but is gdb debugger for linux?

Comment: I don't understand your question. First, I recommend using Linux to learn C programming, since Linux is very student- and developer- friendly (e.g. it has [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) that is very handy). Then, I guess that [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) will provide you a port of GCC and of `gdb` to Windows. However, I never used Windows in my life. At last [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is *not* a compiler (just an IDE)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thankyou so much but what is the advantages of using linux over windows? if i use linux can i understand how recursion, call stack and also inspect variables or debug program thoroughly?

Comment: I am biased. I never used Windows. But, AFAIK, Linux is mostly made of free software (whose source code you can study, and that is an advantage) and Linux has [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), and its `gdb` works well. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54041928/841108) answer. However, recursion is a difficult concept. Read also [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first question on why `while` doesn't work, lets see how code runs in this case
Starting from a simple example lets say our `char[]` is only `GH\0` for simplicity, 
Well, its a little bit hard to explain but lets try
at first `back` is called and `k` points to `G`, as it is not `\0`, `back` is called again with `k` being `++`ed so it is pointing to 'H' and again it is not `\0` so `back` is called with another `++k` in which this time is `\0`, so `while` is not executed and `printf` does its job, now the execution return to second `back` call, where it was called with `H` input, but as we `++`ed it, we moved it on the stack and now it is pointing to `\0` again, so second `printf` runs, now only first `back` call is remained, guess where `k` is pointing to? right, it is pointing to `H`(dont forget `++`), so again `while` is executed, but the input is `++k` which in turn is `\0`, so the new called `back` immediately returns with a `printf`, again we are in first `back` call but this time is pointing to `\0` so another `printf` and we are done,
to understand the sequence better i suggest run this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void back(char*k)
{
    printf("%c",'O');

    while(*k) //->not work??
    {
        back(++k);
    }

    printf("%c",'f');
}

int main()
{
    char k[]="he";
    back(k);
    return 0;
}
```

the expected out put is `OOOffOff`

Comment: thankyou so much, really help me to understand recursive. can i ask one more thing, after reached "\0" and executed printf and back to first back call where k pointing to h, is it still inside the while loop and do the call "back(++k)"  again? so "while" will not become false until *k is "\0" ?   it will keep call "back (++k)"?     the different from "if" is if will control recursion until *k false so stop calling back(++k) and execute next line after each recursion call but "while " will keep call "back(++k)" until it reach "\0" ?

Comment: @Vixf, Welcome, yes, thats it, `if` just checks if in the current call another call should be made or not, but `while` forces the string to go again and again in the function until null is reached

Comment: thankyou! may i know what program do you use to trace or debug simple program like this?

Comment: @Vixf, I mainly develop C framework in embedded environments, and each platform has its own tool, but for example you provided I just used an [online C compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) , no debug tool, I just tried to understand how code flows by reading code and simplifying it, then  tested it with `printf` outputs to make sure I was right, in this example IMHO, this was enough, but in complex problems, a good debug platform is essential, as I said I have no idea what to use for PC apps, (if u r curious, I am using Xillinx SDK as my mainly EDK for embedded :D)