# how do I load a file for c++ on mac

Tags: c++

I am trying to load my file with C++ using ifstream, however it just wouldn't work. I use Atom with Xcode as compiler on my Mac.

This pops up:

> ```
> dyn3180-214:~ joshua$ /var/folders/y6/jrfdjlsx0nqcxyfvsrfw6bnw0000gn/T/excersice ; exit;
> file was not opened correctly
> logout
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){
  std::ifstream infile;
  infile.open("numbers.txt");
  if(!infile.is_open()){
    std::cout<<"file was not opened correctly"<<std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  int n;
  while(infile>>n){
    std::cout<<n<<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you running your executable at the directory the file is located in?

Comment: Assuming you have required read permission, you can use absolute path or make sure your current directory contains the required file. If you have write permissions to the directory, an ofstream would generate a file in this directory.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, I am running my .cpp file in the same folder as the .txt file.

Comment: @GyaptiJain how do I do that on MacOS, if you got any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? We need a [mcve]

Comment: @AlanBirtles on the terminal this shows up:                                                   dyn3180-214:~ joshua$ /var/folders/y6/jrfdjlsx0nqcxyfvsrfw6bnw0000gn/T/excersice                                   ; exit;
file was not opened correctly
logout

Comment: How are you running your program? Presumably from xcode? What have you set the working directory to?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, I run it form Xcode, and I haven't changed the working directory yet, is that why?

Comment: Yes, i can't remember what the default is but as your code isn't working it obviously isn't the directory containing your text file

Comment: @AlanBirtles I tried to go on Xcode and go to File>Workspace Setting, but and change it to my file containing the .cpp and .txt, but somehow I still can't load my file..

Comment: I still don't understand why students are not told to compile on the command line. IDEs are always confusing them. But that is not OP's fault.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396378/change-the-working-directory-in-xcode

Answer (score 1):

Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and also the [documentation of GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) (or of whatever debugger you have on your machine).

Compile your program (that is the C++ file, let's name it `josh.cc`, shown in your question)  with all warnings and debug info. I recommend to compile it *on the command line* with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g josh.cc -o joshprog` (read [*how to invoke GCC*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) for details) then to debug it with `gdb ./joshprog` and to run it in a terminal as `./joshprog`.

The point is that **your IDE** (Atom + XCode) **is *not* helping you. It hides you important details** (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54041928/841108) answer, it also works for MacOSX or other Unix systems). That is why I strongly recommend compiling (and running, and debugging) your code with *explicit* [commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_(computing)) that you are typing in a [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) for your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) and understanding (so read the documentation of *every* command that you are using). Once you are fluent with compilation on Unix systems, you might eventually switch to an IDE (but you need to understand what your IDE is doing on your behalf, and what commands it is running).

You could add into your code something displaying the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) by using [getcwd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) (which *requires* `#include <unistd.h>` on POSIX system), maybe something like

```
char mycwdbuf[80];
memset (mycwdbuf, 0, sizeof(mycwdbuf));
if (getcwd(mycwdbuf, sizeof(mycwdbuf)-1) != NULL)
   std::cout << "current directory is " << mycwdbuf << std::endl;
```

By doing that, you'll probably understand how is your program started and in which working directory. I guess that it was not started in the working directory that you wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, select the `project navigator`, then click on your `project`. This will open the `project editor`. Select the `Build Phases` tab. Open the dropdown for `Copy Files`. Set `Destination` to `Products Directory`. Add a `Subpath` if you have to. Drag the necessary files into the `project editor` or add them via `+`.

[Example: During the *build phase*, project files associated with the target will be copied to the designated *subpath* in the directory within the *Products directory*.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9AjR.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

I think, Xcode generating the  .o (object file ) file in different directory, and your .txt is present in different directory. I do code in Xcode, it always generate the .o file in different directory.

Comment: where should I move my .txt file to? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: One easy way, compile your program through terminal it will create object file in the same directory.