# make gives me a error I don't understand with TurboC

Tags: c, linux, turbo-c, kbhit

I am trying to learn C, for fun.
I am using a Linux distro.
I am trying to compile a program which uses `kbhit()`.
I found a way to this with TurboC (http://www.sandroid.org/TurboC/#Download).

I followed the instructions but `make` gives me this:

```
gettext.c: Dans la fonction « gettextTurboC »:
gettext.c:93:13: warning: les cibles pointées dans l'affectation de « int8_t * » {alias « signed char * »} vers « uint8_t * » {alias « unsigned char * »} diffèrent dans la plage signée [-Wpointer-sign]
   TurboData = (int8_t *) dest;
             ^
In file included from TurboC.h:60,
                 from conio.h:49,
                 from gettext.c:42:
TurboC.h:250:14: error: expected « ) » before « int32_t »
 #define long int32_t
              ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/curses.h:1238:66: note: dans l'expansion de la macro « long »
 #define PAIR_NUMBER(a) (NCURSES_CAST(int,((NCURSES_CAST(unsigned long,(a)) & A_COLOR) >> NCURSES_ATTR_SHIFT)))
                                                                  ^~~~
gettext.c:124:10: note: pour correspondre à ce « ( »
  Color = PAIR_NUMBER (ch & A_COLOR);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
gettext.c:125:23: warning: les cibles pointées dans le passage de l'argument 2 de « pair_content » diffèrent dans la plage signée [-Wpointer-sign]
  pair_content (Color, &dFore, &dBack);
                       ^~~~~~
In file included from TurboC.h:60,
                 from conio.h:49,
                 from gettext.c:42:
/usr/include/curses.h:746:28: note: « short int * » attendu mais l'argument est de type « uint16_t * » {alias « short unsigned int * »}
 extern NCURSES_EXPORT(int) pair_content (NCURSES_PAIRS_T,NCURSES_COLOR_T*,NCURSES_COLOR_T*);  /* implemented */
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
gettext.c:125:31: warning: les cibles pointées dans le passage de l'argument 3 de « pair_content » diffèrent dans la plage signée [-Wpointer-sign]
  pair_content (Color, &dFore, &dBack);
                               ^~~~~~
In file included from TurboC.h:60,
                 from conio.h:49,
                 from gettext.c:42:
/usr/include/curses.h:746:28: note: « short int * » attendu mais l'argument est de type « uint16_t * » {alias « short unsigned int * »}
 extern NCURSES_EXPORT(int) pair_content (NCURSES_PAIRS_T,NCURSES_COLOR_T*,NCURSES_COLOR_T*);  /* implemented */
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:126: gettext.o] Error 1
```

I really don't know what to do with this error:

```
TurboC.h:250:14: error: expected « ) » before « int32_t »
#define long int32_t
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: The first thing you need to do before having your breakfast is uninstall Turbo C and make a note for yourself to never touch it again. Then you can proceed with learning C using a modern C compiler that comes with your Linux distro.

Comment: It would be helpful if the output were in English and some sample code were available (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without code, it's only guessing, but is `int32_t` defined?

Comment: Thank you for helping me, is geany a modern C compiler?

Comment: Your distro should have gcc as default, I guess...

Comment: See http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html for a start.

Comment: Yes, gcc is present in the OS. Obviously I have to give up TurboC. Now I will focus on finding a modern C compiler and how to compile. Thank you for the link about gcc.

Comment: @n.m. They never installed Turbo C. These are gcc error messages. You seem to be mixing up TurboC and Turbo C  (which is understandable , "TurboC" was a dreadful choice of name for this project)

Comment: GCC is a modern enough C compiler. Use it (with all warnings and debug info) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yoursourcecode.c -o yourbinary` for a single source `yoursourcecode.c` program. Then read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Avoid naming programs "TurboC" because that refer to an ancient C compiler that you should forget. Notice that Linux (or the C11 standard [n1570](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)...) don't have `kbhit`. You might want to use [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

Comment: die Turbo C die

Comment: @M.M Thanks, I have looked at this TurboC thing, I was not aware of it. Apparently it's a library for porting MS DOS based code to gcc based compilers. Unless one already has some MS DOS based code to port, this library is not needed. It is certainly not needed for studying C. So OP should uninstall it just the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to learn C, for fun. I am using a Linux distro.

A Linux distribution is an excellent choice to learn C. Notice that it is made of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), whose source code you could study. You'll learn a lot by studying the source code of *small* free software programs written in C (e.g. those from [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), or a simple [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) like [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell), etc.).

If you want to learn C programming, start first with simple command line programs using [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) (a program which handles directly the keyboard is something complex, not for newbies) and restrict yourself to use only the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) at first.

<sup>(the code in your question is not in standard C -since it uses some external library-; I don't recommend trying that at first)</sup>

Later, when you are more familiar with the [C programming language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), you could use some external [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)). A Linux distribution has lots of them. You may need to install development [packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) for them, e.g. `libncurses-dev` on Debian or Ubuntu for `ncurses`.

A very important notion in C is [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Learn more about it, avoid it, be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526702/841108) of it.

> I am trying to compile a program which uses kbhit()

**Notice that `kbhit` and `<conio.h>` are not in the C11 standard** (see [n1570](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)...), and they are not in the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), **so don't use them** (and you won't find any direct equivalent on Linux or POSIX).

On Linux, you might want to use [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). Of course, you need to spend a few days learning it and studying its documentation. You won't find a *direct* equivalent to `kbhit`. Read the [NCURSES programming howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

You may want to use some non-standard libraries (Linux has lots of them). Then read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

The terminal (and [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator), and the [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline)) is a complex thing. Read [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/), [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html), [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html). You really want to use some library such as `ncurses` (or perhaps [`readline`](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)).

[geany](https://www.geany.org/) is not a compiler, but a [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54041928/841108) answer to a related question.

You probably want to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, such as GNU [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). It will run the [`gcc` compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/) for you. So read [*How to invoke GCC*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

Once you are familiar with C programming in general, you might want to learn more about Linux programming, so read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/).

PS. [TurboC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Turbo_C) is an ancient C compiler (not standard conforming) that you should even forget. It does not exist on Linux. GCC is a good, standard conforming, C compiler. You should use it with all warnings and debug info, i.e. compile `yoursourcecode.c` as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yoursourcecode.c -o yourbinary` on Linux. Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). The [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) tool is also very useful (and available on Linux) to debug [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

When asking questions on StackOverflow, be sure to set your [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)) to English. We are not supposed to decipher compiler diagnostics in French.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me. This is exactly the answer I needed!

Comment: I'll study all what you gave me and will not hesitate to send you a email when It will be necessary, thank you Basile.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer:** I am leaving the question of usefulness of studying Turbo C in our century aside.

The problem lies in the macro definition at TurboC.h:250:

```
#define long int32_t
```

This is an attempt to redefine the built-in type `long` through `int32_t`. The latter is defined in `stdint.h`, supplied by the compiler vendor. The definition of `int32_t` is such that it is ultimately mapped on a built-in signed integral type which is 32 bit long. Given that on modern mainstream architectures `int` is 32-bit long, a typical definition of `int32_t` look like this:

```
typedef int int32_t;
```

In any case, `int32_t` is a typedef-name.

Defining `long` via `int32_t` as a macro means that all subsequent occurrences of the token `long` are replaced with the token `int32`. This, among other consequences, breaks legitimate constructs like `unsigned long`: after macro expansion this construct is rendered as `unsigned int32_t`.

Now, combining `unsigned` with a typedef-name is illegal. C syntax specifies that to designate an integer type we have to use *either* a typedef-name *or* a combination of keywords such as `unsigned` and `long`, but not both at the same time.

How GCC reports this error is somewhat confusing. While processing a statement,

```
Color = PAIR_NUMBER (ch & A_COLOR);
```

it expands the function-like macro `PAIR_NUMBER`, which is defined in such a way that it contains a sequence of tokens `unsigned` and `long`. `long` is then further expanded as `int32_t`, which produces a sequence of tokens `unsigned` and `int32_t`. At the place of expansion the compiler does not expect a typedef-name following `unsigned`, as syntax forbids that.

It then presumes that this invalid combination of tokens is a result of a missing right parenthesis somewhere. This presumption is in this case wrong and leads to a confusing error message.

Comment: thank you for the time you took to write tour answer

Answer (score 2):

The "TurboC" project you are trying to use probably only ever worked for simple programs on a specific gcc version of the author's computer. The error messages suggest major, unfixable problems. I would advise not trying to use it.

Instead you could learn C in some other way that doesn't involve trying to build Turbo C source code. If you're looking for something similar then maybe search for `ncurses` example programs or tutorials.

Once you learn the language better you will probably be able to come back to the original source code you're looking at now and be able to port it to ncurses directly.

Comment: I will look at ncurses, thank you.