# What is the proper paradigm of creating a list of pointers?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I find myself *so frequently* thoughtlessly writing classes that add pointers to objects which are later destroyed to lists, which results in a lot of segfaults, but the problem is that sometimes I simply *can't* come up with a better solution than to store a list of pointers. It does my head in that there doesn't seem to be a simple way of just "storing temporary objects that you can't copy" in C++. Is there a paradigm I'm missing on how to do this effectively?

For example, I'll have a class that looks something like this:

```
class MyClass
public:
   std::vector<OtherClass *> other_objects;
   void method() {
      OtherObject other_object = create_other_object();
      other_objects.push_back(&other_object);
   }
```

One reason you may want to do this is because you use the `other_objects` elsewhere (as arguments to other functions) and you can't copy `OtherObject` instances (which could happen if the `OtherObject` copy constructor was private for example).

Of course, once you attempt to use `other_objects` elsewhere in code, the memory each pointer points to will have already been destroyed.

I write a lot of Python code, and I use this sort of structure *very* often, where a method populates an iterable with objects that exist solely in the scope of the method. Is there a way to do this effectively in C++? Could I do my own memory management to keep the temporary objects in the method alive beyond the scope of the method?

Comment: Better not use raw pointers at all but [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the concept, I'm only a beginner in C++. Could you share some references or elaborate on how it solves my issue?

Comment: As I wrote, it takes at least a year to learn these advanced topics. See your C++ book, a year's worth of learning can't really be reduced to a brief answer on stackoverflow. C++ is hard.

Comment: @texasbruce: My opinion is that a decade is needed to master C++. A year is certainly not enough. And very few people master C++ (and I don't claim to, even if I know some of it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the proper paradigm of creating a list of pointers in C++?

Combine [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (or perhaps some other [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)) with some [smart pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) class (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)) such as [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

As a rule of thumb (sometimes wrong) avoid [raw pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#raw_pointer) and prefer smart pointers. [Memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) is a tricky topic. If you read some book on [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) (e.g. the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/)) you'll learn the relevant concepts, terminology and techniques (and these apply even with [manual memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_memory_management) such as [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) - which some people view as a primitive form of GC). [Circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) are painful to handle (be aware of [weak references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference), e.g. [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)).

It would take a *lot* of space and time to explain all this in details (and I don't have time or motivation or even all the skills for that) here. Read a good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book and refer to some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) (and later perhaps to the [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or something newer). Be aware that the [memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)) of C++ is difficult to understand (for anyone).

Be aware of the [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

On some operating systems and/or C++ implementations, you can find tools, such as [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) or the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) of [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) or [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), which should help you to debug then avoid [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) (details are compiler and/or OS specific). And in *some few*  cases (probably a minority of them), you might consider using a garbage collector library (such as [Boehm's GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019003/841108), or [MPS](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps)).

> Is there a way to do this effectively in C++?

I don't know of any efficient, universal and simple way (and [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) make me believe there cannot be one) to manage memory. Your mileage will vary. You need to precisely understand your memory management and other programming constraints and objectives and make your own trade-offs. See Norvig's [opinion](https://norvig.com/21-days.html). There is [*No Silver Bullet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet).

---

PS. **C++ is an *extremely difficult* programming language**. Prepare yourself to spend a lot of time (years, not months; perhaps decades) and efforts to learn it. Look also, for inspiration, into the source code of some well written [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) coded in C++. I don't claim to be a C++ master (even if my daily job is about designing and implementing some static source code [analyzers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) for it). I believe that there might be only a few dozens (or perhaps a few hundreds) of C++ masters on this planet, and I am not among them.

PPS. I am biased, but I recommend [using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54041928/841108) Linux on your development machine to learn C++ programming, precisely because it has lots of useful tools.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no reason you would ever do this:

```
  OtherObject other_object = create_other_object();
  other_objects.push_back(&other_object);
```

This creates a temporary object, and you store the pointer in a list, and then the object is destroyed.

This is the main difference with Python. In Python, every object is a reference to a Python object, even integers. In C++, you have object on the stack (like yours) or on the heap (created through `new`, `make_unique`...). If you want to mimick Python behavior, you need objects on the heap.

There are only three valid patterns, depending on what `create_object()` does:

- it create an object and returns it by value. In that case, wrap it with `make_unique` to get a copy. This pattern is usually not very useful and not practical.
- it create a new object on the heap and expects the calling code to handle memory management. The prototype is thus: `std::unique_ptr<OtherClass> create_other_object();`
- it creates a new object but doesn't expect the calling code to handle memory management, in which case the prototype should be `OtherClass* create_other_object();`

In your case, it's probably the second case:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<OtherClass>> other_objects;
void method() {
    other_objects.push_back(create_other_object());
}
```